# Determining app's signing identity at runtime

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I've developed an app that uses push notifications. Along the way, I've needed to sign my app using a development profile (general dev work), an ad hoc distribution profile (e.g. for testing) and finally using an app store distribution profile.

I can never keep track of which version I have on my device, and sometimes when a notification doesn't arrive it'll take me a while to figure out that it is because of the way it is signed.

Is there some way to determine the signing identity at runtime? I would like to change a color or add some other visual customization to help me know which environment to expect notifications from.

Or some other way to achieve the same perhaps?

Comment: Maybe, you can pass a compile Flag, i just don't know who you will find out which profile are you using

Comment: You can use DEBUG macro to differ Development profile from adhoc and AppStore, but i can't tell you how to diff AppStore Profiles and Adhoc Profiles